# return sum of count from element.all protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I need to calculate the sum of count of all elements matched the filter.

Here is the function:

```
this.filterPoolRecordGrid = function (searchText, callback) {
    var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
    element.all(By.repeater("(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index")).then(function (eles) {
        var countR = 0;
        eles.forEach(function (ele) {
            ele.all(By.repeater('(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid')).filter(function (ele) {
                return  ele.getText().then(function (text) {
                    return text.indexOf(searchText) > -1;
                })
            }).count().then(function (value) {
                countR += value;
                callback(countR);
            });
        });
    });

    defer.fulfill();
    return defer.promise;
};
```

Here is how I use it:

```
it('Test valid input into groups search box', function () {
            poolRecordsPage.filterPoolRecordGrid('two', function (count) {
                console.info(count);
            });
```

Via using callback, I am able to return the sum, however, since I use element.forEach. the output like below, but I only need the final one, that is the last 2.

```
Started
```

0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) instead:

```
this.filterPoolRecordGrid = function (searchText) {
    return element.all(By.repeater("(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index")).map(function (ele) {
        return ele.all(By.repeater('(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid')).filter(function (ele) {
            return  ele.getText().then(function (text) {
                return text.indexOf(searchText) > -1;
            })
        }).count();
    }).then(function (counts) {
        return counts.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
poolRecordsPage.filterPoolRecordGrid('two').then(function (count) {
    console.log(count);
});
```

Or:

```
expect(poolRecordsPage.filterPoolRecordGrid('two')).toEqual(10);
```